# Problema Com Internet Explorer que não tenho no Chrome e no Firefox

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

No Internet Explorer aparece-me: Acesso negado neste scope:

```
$scope.login = {
  "user": window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
  "check": window.localStorage.getItem("valor"),
  "lingua": window.localStorage.getItem("lingua")
}
```

Este login e de um form, que tens os ng-model's user, check e lingua.

No Chrome e no Firefox não me dá erro.

Comment: Qual versão do IE? qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: Versão 11  o erro  é: Acesso negado e indica me a linha de código em cima digitada

Comment: O erro pode estar nas configurações do seu IE, ele pode não estar permitindo que o site utilize o localStorage.

Comment: O `IE` é um erro

Comment: Pelo que me apercebi tinha a haver com o localStorage

Usei este plugin: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Ficou a Funcionar. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que me apercebi tinha a haver com o localStorage

Usei este plugin: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Ficou a Funcionar.
Obrigado